# How to disable the server side of Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, backend

I've made a new project in NuxtJs.

When I run `npm run dev`, however, it shows the following in my terminal:

```
√ Client
  Compiled successfully in 7.88s

√ Server
  Compiled successfully in 5.14s
```

Does this mean that NuxtJs automatically boots a Front-end and a back-end? If so, how can I disable/delete this back-end. A back-end will be made apart from my front-end, actually.

Comment: The documentation covers how to configure for various [deployment targets](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/deployment-targets), including static hosting … but if you are planning to have an API and aren’t planning to use it with server-side rendering then perhaps Nuxt.js isn’t a good choice in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuxt is not a backend in a sense that it will replace Express, Laravel, Ruby on Rails or alike. It's a meta framework with various capabilities like SSR (Server Side Rendering), SSG (Static Site Generation), SPA (Single Page App) and some other in between if you're using Nuxt3.

You could disable the "server" part of Nuxt by setting `ssr: false` but you will lose quite some performance overall. It will mainly be an improved version of Vue (understand from a Developer eXperience part) but will not be as fast as it's supposed to be for your end users.

Consider keeping Nuxt as an SSG (`ssr: true` + `target: 'static'`) alongside your actual "API backend".

PS: pretty much all JS meta frameworks work in this kind of way. Mainly because doing things on the server is faster/safer than doing that on your user's crappy laptop from 2000 (SPA's only basically) via pure client side.

Comment: "Nuxt is not a backend in a sense that it will replace Express" is what I was looking for, thanks! I was confused by the "√ Server" server in my console.

Comment: @Craws if you're not used to JS meta frameworks, SSR can be quite confusing. Totally understandable!

Comment: I think this answer is directed towards Nuxt 2. Nuxt 3 with Nitro seems much more full-fledged.

Comment: @CharlieSchliesser yes, this is tagged as [tag:nuxt.js], hence the v2 mostly.